# How to load a html file's content into javascript variable in django?

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, templates

I'd like to insert contents of abc.html after a `div` when some event fires.

I tried

```
var content = {% include "path/to/abc.html" %};

$(".myDiv").click(function() {

$("#anotherDiv").insertAfter(content);
});
```

However, it seems `{% include %} fails because of some sort of parsing error. (abc.html is multi-line)

`abc.html` contains django filters/tags.

any thoughts?

Comment: @dan-klasson: please enlighten me. How?

Comment: You are missing one double-quote in `{% include "path/to/abc.html %}`. Should be `{% include "path/to/abc.html" %}`. Anyway I don't think it will work out, think of other methods then.

Comment: Like asifrc's answer. Maybe try replacing `\n` in the string as well.

Comment: it will not work in that way. You should make a js function that read the files after getting the exact path before showing the content

Comment: this is previewing import file content http://catherinetenajeros.blogspot.com/2013/05/preview-file-before-importing.html. The difference is, this is showing the content when it is import and your is showing the content based on the exact path. If you can understand the flow of the codes, you can get the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One alternative approach would be to put the contents into a hidden div, and just get your click function to unhide it.

Comment: possible to detach it and attach it somewhere else? .detach() and .insertAfter() would seem to do the job.

Answer (score 0):

If abc.html is pure html, then you could do a simple ajax request to load the file, e.g.

```
$(".myDiv").click(function() {
    $.get('path/to/abc.html', {}, function(content) {
        $(content).insertAfter("#anotherDiv");
    });
});
```

Although if you're worried about loadtime, you could load it earlier into a variable.

Let me know if the code makes sense or if you have any questions :)

Comment: Ah, yeah I tried it, unfortunately the html contains django tags. (not pure html), I'll edit my question accordingly